# Mysql - How to select entries from one table based on whether or not I subscribe to them from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, logic

For the life of me I cannot wrap my head around this simple mysql problem. (my brain is fried, almost 16 hours of straight coding).

I have, essentially, the tables *entries* and *subscriptions*

**entries**

- publisherId
- entry

**subscriptions**

- myId
- friendId

I want to be able to select all the entries that are published by all the people I am subscribed to in *subscriptions*.

I would love if it would be possible to do this with codeigniter's activerecord syntax as well, but if it's impossible, plain mysql syntax would be so greatly appreciated.

What concept am I missing here? Is it a simple join or is it a matter of looping through all the people I subscribe to and finding entries that are published by them?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JOIN. In plain SQL:

```
SELECT e.publisherId, e.entry
FROM entries e
JOIN subscriptions s
ON s.friendId = e.publisherId
WHERE s.myId = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

let me know if it works , because I am still learning Active Query records (join is confusing to me :P )

```
$this->db->select('entries.publisherId,entries.entry');
$this->db->from('entries');
$this->db->join('comments', 'subscriptions.friendId = entries.publisherId');
$this->db->where('subscriptions.myId', 1234); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Hi that was very close but it looks like I had to change the third line a tiny bit, thank you so much!

`$this->db->select('entries.publisherId,entries.entry');
$this->db->from('entries');
$this->db->join('subscriptions','subscriptions.friendId = entries.userId');
$this->db->where('subscriptions.userId', 1234);`